# Stampacchia Problem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I need to solve this problem, but don't know how get that particular bound. Please, somebody can help me?

---

Let $V$ a Hilbert space, $a : V\times  V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a bounded bilinear form, symmetric and coercive, and $A : V\rightarrow V^{\prime}$ the linear bounded operator subordinate to $a$ (i.e, $A(u) = a(u,\cdot\ )$). Given $f\in V^{\prime}$ and $U$ a nonempty subset of $V$, convex and closed, the Stampacchia theorem said that there is a unique $u\in U$ such that
$$a(u,v-u)\ \geq\ f(v-u),\quad \forall\ v\in U.$$
Now, let $V_h$ a finite-dimensional subspace of $V$, $U_h$ a subset of $V_h$, nonempty, convex and closed, and set $u_h\in U_h$ the unique solution of the problem
$$a(u_h,v_h-u_h)\ \geq\ f(v_h-u_h),\quad \forall\ v_h\in U_h.$$
Besides, let $H$ a Hilbert such that $V\subseteq H$ with canonical inyection $i:V\rightarrow H$ continuous and dense. Show that if $A(u) - f\in H$, then there is a constant $C$, independent of $V_h$ and $U_h$, such that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\|u - u_h\|_V& \leq & C\left\{\inf_{v_h\in U_h}\left(\|u-v_h\|_V^2 +\ \|A(u)-f\|_H\|u-v_h\|_H\right) \right.\\
& & \left.+\ \|A(u) - f\|_H\inf_{v\in U}\|u_h - v\|_H\right\}^{1/2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

See theorem 1.2, page 4 of this file http://www.stat-athens.aueb.gr/gr/master/sumschool/files/Kravvaritis.pdf